# neo4j how to know you reach end of this path

Tags: neo4j

During neo4j traversal, i want to know the endnode of the path node(full path). But using the following code, it output the path like once reach a node, it output the (new)path. So it is not the end of full path.
how to recognizance the end node of full path.

```
for ( Path path :db.traversalDescription()
        .depthFirst()
        .relationships( Rels.KNOWS,Direction.OUTGOING )
        .traverse( node ) )
{
    output += path + "\n";
    System.out.println(output);
}
```

Comment: I was going to edit this but I'm not 100% sure what OP is saying here.   OP, please clarify your question, it's hard to understand you.  This code will print out a path each time it visits a node.  So if you have a graph A->B->C, you'll get one path A->B, and another A->B->C.   Are you saying that you want to only print the longest paths found, none of the intermediaries?

Answer (score 0):

You can use path.endNode() to get the last node (end node) of each path, or use path.nodes() to get an Iterable with the last element being the end node of the path.

See [http://api.neo4j.org/current/org/neo4j/graphdb/Path.html#endNode()](http://api.neo4j.org/current/org/neo4j/graphdb/Path.html#endNode%28%29)

But as @FrobberOfBits wrote, the traversal will give you all possible paths, so without further limiting conditions or rules, your question is ambigiuous.